# How to group by index and index+1 in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have data input like this:

```
(index,x,y)
(1,0.0,0.0)
(2,-0.1,-0.1)
(3,1.0,-2.2)
...
```

how can I group by [index] and [index + 1] like

```
{(1, 0.0, 0.0), (2, -0.1, -0.1)}
{(2, -0.1, -0.1), (3, 1.0, -2.2)}
...
```

Please help me through this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query (explanation in comments).

```
-- load relation
R = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (index,x,y);

-- project each tuple to 2 different keys
-- one with index and one with index+1
R1 = FOREACH R GENERATE index+0, index, x, y;
R2 = FOREACH R GENERATE index+1, index, x, y;


-- group
result = COGROUP R1 by $0, R2 by $0;

-- clean out wrong combinations
result2 = filter result by NOT(IsEmpty(R1)) and NOT(IsEmpty(R2));

-- flatten the results
result3 = FOREACH result2 GENERATE FLATTEN(R1), FLATTEN(R2);
result4 = FOREACH result3 GENERATE (R1::index,R1::x,R1::y), (R2::index,R2::x,R2::y);
```

The file I used to test contains the following:

```
1,0.0,0.0
2,-0.1,-0.1
3,1.0,-2.2
```

Note that the parentheses are not present, but you can filter them away using a simple preprocessing script.

The dumps of intermediate results are:

`DUMP R;`

```
(1,0.0,0.0)
(2,-0.1,-0.1)
(3,1.0,-2.2)
```

`DUMP R1;`

```
((1,1,0.0,0.0))
((2,2,-0.1,-0.1))
((3,3,1.0,-2.2))
```

`DUMP R2;`

```
((1,1,0.0,0.0))
((2,2,-0.1,-0.1))
((3,3,1.0,-2.2))
```

`DUMP result;`

```
(1,{(1,1,0.0,0.0)},{})
(2,{(2,2,-0.1,-0.1)},{(2,1,0.0,0.0)})
(3,{(3,3,1.0,-2.2)},{(3,2,-0.1,-0.1)})
(4,{},{(4,3,1.0,-2.2)})
```

`DUMP result2;`

```
(2,{(2,2,-0.1,-0.1)},{(2,1,0.0,0.0)})
(3,{(3,3,1.0,-2.2)},{(3,2,-0.1,-0.1)})
```

`DUMP result3;`

```
(2,2,-0.1,-0.1,2,1,0.0,0.0)
(3,3,1.0,-2.2,3,2,-0.1,-0.1)
```

`DUMP result4;`

```
((2,-0.1,-0.1),(1,0.0,0.0))
((3,1.0,-2.2),(2,-0.1,-0.1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The below approach will work for your case.
**input:**

```
1,0.0,0.0
2,-0.1,-0.1
3,1.0,-2.2
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS(index:int,x:double,y:double);
B = FILTER A BY index>=1;
C = FILTER A BY index>1;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE ($0-1) AS dindex,index,x,y;
E = JOIN B BY index, D BY dindex;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE TOBAG(TOTUPLE(B::index,B::x,B::y),TOTUPLE(D::index,D::x,D::y));
DUMP F;
```

**Output:**

```
({(1,0.0,0.0),(2,-0.1,-0.1)})
({(2,-0.1,-0.1),(3,1.0,-2.2)})
```